# Sonatype Nexus adds optionalDependencies to dependencies

Tags: npm, nexus

We're using Nexus as internal NPM repository. For whatever reason, it adds all the `optionalDependencies` to `dependencies`.

So if I publish (assume proper JSON):

`{
  version: '1.0',
  dependencies: {
    a: '1'
  },
  optionalDependencies: {
    b: '1',
    c: '1'
  }
}`

Then I get 

`{
  version: '1.0',
  dependencies: {
    a: '1',
    b: '1',
    c: '1'
  },
  optionalDependencies: {
    b: '1',
    c: '1'
  }
}`

both in metatada (e.g. if I request it via browser) and in `package.json` of installed package.

Any tips?

Comment: version used is 2.11.2-06

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that this is one of the hidden "features" of npm: see https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3502.

If a dependency is present in both `dependencies` and `optionalDependencies`, the latter takes precedence ([see here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#optionaldependencies)), so this change in `package.json` shouldn't affect you.

If it does, however, you can always explicitly tell `npm` to skip these dependencies using `npm install --no-optional` (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install).